# Store the current filename in a given register

Tags: cut-copy-paste, register

When I exchange with colleagues about the code, when I refer to given functions, I like to also mention the file.

Since this exchange does not usually take place within vim, I usually copy them out using the `*` register.

It's easy to copy the name of the function (typically, I would use `"*yiw`). However, for the file name, I can only think of using the command line as

```
:let @*=expand('%:t')
```

So I know that I can map that to a command. But is there a built-in way to achieve that?

And maybe there is a way to set to any register, which would not be available with a fixed mapping to the line above?

Comment: use use the builtin `%` register. It contains the filename for the current buffer, but you may still need to run `expand()` on it, if you just want to have the full path or just the final filename

Comment: Ok, but how do I copy the content of `%` onto `*`?

Comment: ``let @*=@%`` ?

Comment: See @VivianDeSmedt comment

Comment: I  do as @VivianDeSmedt suggests; at that point, I can trim needless leading components (likes /Users/…/) later if need be, but since pwd is usually the project root @% is usually the most unambiguous path reference.